# Python shelve get() and keys() methods return inconsistent results

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, shelve

I am running code that writes data to shelve (Python 3.6 in conda env). While checking output I noticed that get() method return value for key "5000", yet methods keys() and items() do not return this key and greater keys. Greater keys are recent keys as I was inserting keys incrementally.

```
import shelve
reviews_translated = shelve.open("../../datasets/raw_reviews_translated_helsinki")

print('bool', '5000' in list(reviews_translated.keys()))

print('keys()', sorted(map(int, list(reviews_translated.keys()))))

print('get("5000")', reviews_translated.get('5000')[0][:3])
reviews_translated.close()
```

Output:

> bool False

> keys() [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600, 3700, 3800, 3900, 4000, 4100, 4200, 4300, 4400, 4500, 4600, 4700, 4800, 4900]

> get("5000") ['46d6f9f7a130fea143f7d87d7d47b75d', 'a9ca1733b5dee4d288c12e15108358c8', '02c2e703ac1ec44d3e84d8479670868e']

Why cannot I see all present keys using keys()? What is convenient way to check what keys are inserted?

Thanks for any suggestion :)

Comment: @Patric Artner I think this conversion was for sorting purposes. Arthur, can you try to call `reviews_translated.sync()` ?

Comment: Thx, Peter. Yes, I tried to open() with writeback=True and then sync(). Nothing changed.
Sorting? Can you explain? Keys() does not return all keys present in shelve. That's all.

Comment: Arthur, I cannot explain this behaviour. Can you share the file with us?